# How does locking work for state file in terraform?

Tags: terraform, state, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to store the state file for my terraform configuration on a remote backend, but I don't understand how the terraform state file is locked to prevent others from tampering with resources.

The code is present in a git repository and anyone with access to it can make changes to the code, the pipeline has been configured in a way so that upon any commit the terraform scripts will run.

If anyone with access to code can make changes to the terraform code & anyone with access to the resource can make changes in the console, how is terraform state locking preventing others from tampering with the resources that I have created?

Comment: I wrote a blog and a package to handle this.
blog: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/multicloud-terraform-states-b8686de20d60
python package: https://github.com/tomarv2/tfremote

Answer (score 3):

That is **not** what state locking is for. State locking is for **locking the state during a deployment** such that no two terraform processes try to update the same state at the same time.

That has nothing to do with protecting your resources from changes by other developers. That is something you need to handle at an organizational level, maybe through differently permitted users, maybe by having separate accounts, code reviews to prevent accidental destruction, maybe SCPs, ...

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Thanks for this.